# How to convert one type to another using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a two types that are very similar (i.e. the member names are very similar).

Is there an elegant way to copy one type to another, without having to copy each individual member by hand?

**Update**

Here is some sample source code:

```
main()
{
  FromCsvFile x = new FromCsvFile(fileName);
  OptionsEnt y = x.ToOptionsEnt(); // See helper function below.
}

// Chained helper function to convert type "FromCsvFile" to type "OptionsEnt".
// Want to replace this with something more elegant (perhaps with reflection?).
// Notice the corner cases, i.e. the "ExpirationDate" is a special conversion.
public static OptionsEnt ToOptionsEnt(this FromCsvFile fromCsvFile)
{
  return new OptionsEnt
           {
             Last = fromCsvFile.Last,
             Ask = fromCsvFile.Ask,
             Bid = fromCsvFile.Bid,
             Delta = fromCsvFile.Delta,
             EODsnapshotNewYorkTime = fromCsvFile.EODsnapshotNewYorkTime,
             Exchange = fromCsvFile.Exchange,
             ExpirationDate = fromCsvFile.Expiration.ToTypeIceDate(),
             Gamma = fromCsvFile.Gamma,
             IV = fromCsvFile.IV,
             LastDate = fromCsvFile.Date.ToTypeIceDate(),
             AdjustedStockClose = fromCsvFile.AdjustedStockClose,
             MeanPrice = fromCsvFile.MeanPrice,
             OptionType = fromCsvFile.OptionType == "C" ? OptionTypeEnum.enCall : OptionTypeEnum.enPut,
             OpenInterest = fromCsvFile.OpenInterest,
             Rho = fromCsvFile.Rho,
             StockSymbol = fromCsvFile.SymbolStock,
             StrikePrice = fromCsvFile.StrikePrice,
             Symbol = fromCsvFile.Symbol,
             StockPriceForIV = fromCsvFile.StockPriceForIV,
             Star = fromCsvFile.Star,
             Theta = fromCsvFile.Theta,
             Vega = fromCsvFile.Vega,
             Volume = fromCsvFile.Volume,
             IVnotInterpolated = fromCsvFile.IVnotInterpolated
          };
}
```

**Update**

Decided to go with AutoMapper.

Here is the code that replaces *all* of the code above (assuming that all member names are of the same name and type):

```
main()
{
  FromCsvFile x = new FromCsvFile(fileName);
  OptionsEnt y = Mapper.Map<FromCsvFile, OptionsEnt>(x);
}
```

As we need some custom converters (i.e. DateTime >> IceDateTime), here is the extra line of code that includes a custom mapping for the parameter "ExpirationDate". Adding this line avoids an exception being thrown as it doesn't know how to convert dates from one format to another.

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<DateTime, typeIceDate>().ConvertUsing(ConverterIceTypeIceDate.ToTypeIceDate);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870656/object-to-object-mapping-utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)?

For example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FromCsvFile, OptionsEnt >();
return Mapper.Map<FromCsvFile, OptionsEnt>(fromCsvFile);
```

Comment: This sounds great. However, how would it handle the corner cases? ExpirationDate is of type DateTime in one type, and type IceDateTime in the other type. Its easy to convert between these types - but I guess the mapping will fail unless I tell it to "Convert IceDateTime to DateTime with extension method .ToDateTime".

Comment: Aha! Found it: You can add custom type converters, see http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters&referringTitle=Home.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for that. It will allow you to simply define that class `OptionsEnt` should be mapped to `FromCsvFile` and if they have the properties with same names and types then you won't need to define anything else.

Otherwise you'll have to iterate by properties.

Comment: You mention "Iterate by properites" how would I do this? The problem is that there is some corner cases, i.e. ExpirationDate is of type "DateTime" in in one type and type "IceDateTime" in the other.

Comment: @Gravitas, You will also specify in AutoMapper that `IceDateTime` can be mapped to regular `DateTime` and AM will handle properties of both types.

Answer (score 0):

See [Copyable: A framework for copying or cloning .NET objects](http://ox.no/software/copyable). Its slightly slower (it uses reflection), but it has one advantage: you can alter the source to handle corner cases where the member variables need a little bit of work to convert.

For example, in the sample source code in the question, member variable "ExpirationDate" is of type "DateTime" in one type, and type "IceDateTime" in the other (you need to convert the date format with the extension method .ToDateTime).

Here is the source (see the [original blog entry](http://ox.no/posts/extension-methods-for-copying-or-cloning-objects/comment-page-2#comment-1333) for more source):

```
// Modification to original source code.
Type type = instance.GetType();

if (instance.GetType().Name == "DataTable")
{
    // Added to handle custom type.
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)instance;
    copy = dt.Copy();
}
else if (instance.GetType().Name == "DataSet")
{
    // Added to handle custom type.
    DataSet ds = (DataSet)instance;
    copy = ds.Copy();
}
else
{
    // This is the original source.
    while (type != null)
    {
        foreach (FieldInfo field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            object value = field.GetValue(instance);
            if (visited.ContainsKey(value))
                field.SetValue(copy, visited[value]);
            else
                field.SetValue(copy, value.Clone(visited));
        }
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
}
return copy;
```

Comment: Decided against Ox - I don't really want to alter the core source code of the mapper to add my custom mappers. I'm using AutoMapper instead.